# How to insert or update multiple rows in Slick in a batch

Tags: scala, slick

I have a slick model which I need to create or update based on sequence provided in insertOrUpdateCalculations method. If there is already a row with (container, order and vendor) volume and weight should be updated. Otherwise new row should be created.

```
case class OrderCalculation(
  id: Long,
  container: Long,
  order: Long,
  vendor: Long,
  volume: Double,
  weight: Double)

class OrderCalculationTable(tag: Tag)
      extends Table[OrderCalculation](tag, "order_calculation") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def order = column[Long]("containerOrder")
  def orderFk =
    foreignKey("order_fk", order, orderTbl)(_.id)
  def vendor = column[Long]("vendor")
  def vendorFk =
    foreignKey("vendor_fk", vendor, vendorTbl)(_.id)
  def container = column[Long]("container")
  def containerFk =
    foreignKey("container_fk", container, containerTbl)(_.id)
  def volume = column[Double]("volume")
  def weight = column[Double]("weight")
  override def * = (
    id,
    container,
    order,
    vendor,
    volume,
    weight
  ) <> ((OrderCalculation.apply _).tupled, OrderCalculation.unapply)
}
```

I need to implement method with signature like below:

```
val orderCalculationTbl = TableQuery[OrderCalculationTable]
case class OrderCalculationSummary(
  orderId: Long,
  containerId: Long,
  vendorId: Long,
  volume: Double,
  weight: Double
 ) 
def insertOrUpdateCalculations(calculations: Seq[OrderCalculationSummary]): Future[Seq[OrderCalculation]] = db.run{
    /// insert or update each record here.
}
```

My primary problem is how to update record if I don't have primary key (id) in the input values, but only 3 other values which are foreign keys to other tables. Basically, I need to have a query that will check these 3 fields and update existing or create new row without primary key provided.

Comment: What's your problem exactly, what you don't know? Here are slick docs about inserting rows https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/queries.html#inserting if you want to load data from the db first and do the diff yourself. There is also insertOrUpdate op if you have necessary keys https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/queries.html#upserting

Comment: From the documentation and examples I've found I couldn't figure out how to update existing record if I don't provide primary key which is ID. In my case I have 3 other fields and need to make a query based on it.

Comment: AFAIK RDBMSs rely on primary key for upsert/replace into operations. You need to load the data first with SELECT, do the diff and then issue UPDATEs or or INSERTs. No shortcuts I am afraid